# sp_addlinkedserver with no catalog details

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, linked-server

I have to access records from view which resides on another server. So the obvious way to do is by using **Linked Server** I successfully created it by using

```
 EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'Server_Name'
```

Now I am able to access records from that server using

```
 SELECT * FROM [Server_Name].[Database_Name].[dbo].[View_Name]
```

After creating Linked Server, I am able to view all databases & there resp tables & views under Catalogs menu of just created Linked Server. I want to hide all this information under Catalog menu.

How to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to do something like this:

DENY VIEW DEFINITION. You cannot remove the user's ability to see the existence of the views and stored procedures, but you can remove the ability to view (most) of the contents in them.

```
deny view definition to limits_role 
go
sp_addrolemember 'limits_role ', 'limits_user'
go
sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'limits_user'
go
```

Then use the this user when defining your linked server.

```
sp_addlinkedsrvlogin [ @rmtsrvname = ] 'rmtsrvname'   
     [ , [ @useself = ] 'TRUE' | 'FALSE' | NULL ]   
     [ , [ @locallogin = ] 'locallogin' ]   
     [ , [ @rmtuser = ] 'rmtuser' ]   
     [ , [ @rmtpassword = ] 'rmtpassword'
```

Full syntax to the above can be found here [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx)

Comment: can you explain what 'limits_role', 'limits_user' to be replaced with? I cant figure out the meaning of above terms. When i try to execute, I m getting errors as 'Cannot find the user 'limits_role', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.' and 'User or role 'limits_user' does not exist in this database.'

Comment: This is just an example.  Take a look at the article for the details necessary for your particular implementation. @UmeshAP